# Laravel dependency injection - bindings

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've just `composer update`d my project this morning and this in turn updated a number of dependencies in my Laravel project. Since this update I have noticed one thing in particular has stopped working.

In one of my command handlers I inject a `Filesystem` dependency and use it in the following way:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem; // NOTE: This is an interface
...
class MyCommandHandler {
    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->filesystem->exists('/directory/that/does/not/exist'))
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed that when calling the `exists` method on the injected `$filesystem` object with a directory that does not exist, the condition passes as if the directory does exist and I end up with problems further on in my code.

I used `get_class()` to output the class of the `$filesystem` object and it ended up being `Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter`. Investigating further I found that I end up with my filesystem operations being handled by the `League\Flysystem` package where previously they were being handled by `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`.

I'm not entirely sure why the change to Flysystem has broken my code but I have a couple of questions regarding dependency injection in Laravel.

1. Is it better to typehint an interface and let the Laravel resolve it from the IoC container (Like I've done here) **OR** is it better to typehint a concrete class (So in my case inject `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`)?
2. Where are the bindings for interface -> implementation defined? Also, can they be modified without changing the core code?

Cheers

**Edit**

Some test code within a controller. Outputs `yes|no`.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
...

public function index(Filesystem $fs)
{
    $testPath = '/path/that/does/not/exist';
    echo $fs->exists($testPath) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    echo '|' . (file_exists($testPath) ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

**Edit 2 - partial answer**

I've done a lot more digging and found out why I'm having problems with the `Flysystem` package implementation:

The `Flysystem` package works using *disks* (Which are defined in *config/filesystems.php*), the default being the local disk. It turns out that this package uses the configuration defined here for each *disk*, in my case the *local* disk. The local disk is by default rooted to the storage path of the application and all paths are then considered relative to that.

So when I was doing `$fs->exists('/does/not/exist')`, the path actually being looked at as `/var/www/myproject/storage/app/does/not/exist`.

It is possible to define as many disks as you like and use the `Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory` package to perform operations relative to that path like this:

**config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path()
    ],
```

**Any controller/command/anything else**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory as Filesystem;
...
class ClassName {
    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(Filesystem $fs)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $fs->disk('public'); // Refers to public disk in config/filesystems.php
    }

    public function method()
    {
        $this->filesystem->exists('path'); // /var/www/myproject/public/path
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea to look in `Storage/App` - all my files are there! Have you considered changing your edit into an answer below?